How best to manage a custom Homebrew .plist file?
Is there a way to manage a custom plist file such that homebrew will respect it and not overwrite it on updates? Or is there another way?
I run 2 versions of mysql; 5.7 and 8 simultaneously, so I've had to change some of the dirs. This works fine except when the plist file is updated in the Cellar, then when a service is restarted brew copies the distribution plist from the Cellar into LaunchAgents.
Thanks
Mike
